# Detect audio coming from microphone

Tags: python, audio, microphone

Ive seen other questions similar to this, but they all involve detecting audio and then recording. I'd like my microphone connected to my computer to always be recording, and any time audio is detected it runs another part of a script. What modules would I need? How would I do this? Im pretty sure this would involve seeing when the audio volume goes above a certain point and then activating the rest of the script, because obviously there will always be some sort of sound coming from the microphone.

Comment: google: https://www.google.com/search?q=python+sound+manipulation

Answer (score 0):

This might help if you want them to say something and then if they say the right word or whatever run the script.

https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/